# IEでフォームにファイルをドラッグアンドドロップでセットしたい

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

ChromeやSafariではドラッグアンドドロップでファイルをフォームにセットできます。（下図参照）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、IEだとこれが実現できません。（ドロップするとその画像をブラウザで開いてしまう）

JavaScriptを使ってIEでもドラッグアンドドロップでファイルをフォームにセットすることはできますか？

Ajaxでファイルアップロードをするプラグインやサンプルコードはたくさん見つかるのですが、「フォームにセットするだけ、サブミットは普通にボタンをクリックしてサブミットする」という情報は見つかりませんでした。

[こちらの情報](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247197/is-it-possible-to-use-html-drag-and-drop-file-uploads-but-without-ajax-xhr)は目的に近かったですが、IEでは機能しませんでした。

何か参考になりそうな情報があれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

ちなみにIEはIE11のような最近のバージョンを対象にしてもOKです。

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが http://filedropjs.org/demo/ こちらを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。私もDragDropでファイルアップロードを行うスクリプトを組んだときにこのような配布されているものを参考に作成しておりました。

Answer (score 1):

以前に似たようなことをやろうとしてハマった経験がありますので、直接の回答ではないのですがご参考になればと思い投稿いたします。

結論から言うと、私の場合もフォームに直接ドロップする事はできませんでした。そのため回避策としてドロップ領域を別途用意(divタグで領域を作りました)して、addEventListenerでdropイベントを追加し、dropイベント内でドロップされたファイル名を取得して表示する、というようなことをやりました。

ただ、私の場合ファイルを複数選択する必要があったため、ファイル名入力フィールドは使用せずに、テーブル要素として表示させていましたので、ファイル名入力フィールドだと取得したファイル名をスクリプト等で表示させることができるかわかりません(確かできなかったように記憶しています、ちょっと自信ないですが)。

このため、submitボタンのイベントにも細工をして、表示している複数のファイルをそれぞれPOSTするような処理を追加しました。

回りくどいようですが、こういう回避策もあるということで。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「submitボタンのイベントにも細工をして、表示している複数のファイルをそれぞれPOSTするような処理を追加しました」というところが気になります。コード例があれば見てみたいです。

Comment: 概要だけお伝えします。
submitボタンと書きましたが、
    <input type='button' onclick='submit()' />
のようにしていました。で、submit()でフォームの内容を取得し、appendでファイル(dataTrasfer.filesを用意した変数に格納している)を追加します。これをXMLHttpRequestのsendで送ります。
    var form =  document.getElementById('transport-form');  
    var formdata = new FormData(form);  
    formdata.append('datanum', files.length); // ファイルArrayのサイズ  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
        formdata.append(i, files[i]);  
    }  
    var request =  new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open(form.method, form.action ,true);  
    request.send(formdata);

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。なるほど、最後はやっぱり力業っぽくなっちゃうんですね。現時点ではできるかできないかの技術調査の段階で、まだ実際に実装するかどうかは未定なのですが、実装する必要が出てきた際はこちらのコードを参考にさせてもらいます。

Answer (score 1):

[IE10 (Win7 32bit)](https://www.modern.ie/ja-jp/virtualization-tools#downloads)で確認しましたが、[ng-file-upload](http://jsfiddle.net/3t50b3fw/)を利用すれば実現可能です。

[image]

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。ただ、これだとサブミットはサブミットボタンをクリックしたタイミングで、ということができないのではないでしょうか？（ドロップした瞬間にアップロード、は避けたいです。）あとAngular JSも今は使っていないので素のJS or jQueryで実現できるソリューションの方がありがたいです。せっかく回答してもらったのにすいません。

Comment: デモを用意してみました
http://jsfiddle.net/59naga/z0p4t1mw/

Comment: jQuery版のデモまで作ってもらってありがとうございます！なるほど、やっぱり最後は自分でフォームの内容を詰め込んでAjaxで送信、っていう形になるんですね。Chromeの標準の動きだと「ドラッグアンドドロップ = ファイル選択したことと同じ = 単純にサブミットできる」のでお手軽だったんですが、IEだと「ドラッグアンドドロップ = jQuery等でファイル選択したことと同じにする = （JSのコードを使わずに）単純にサブミットできる」というふうに実装するのは難しそうですね。。。